# mysql workbench behind proxy

Tags: mysql, proxy

How can I connect to a database server using MySQL workbench while behind a proxy? There seems to be no setting in the workbench UI to do this.

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying, trying hard to make workbench work for my needs, unfortunately this tool is too bug in my opinion. Use something else or go back to shell, do not rely on this crap.

Comment: one more thing, if you really insist on use workbench, just try to create a new user with your mysql and allow this user to read only privileges. Then you can connect, I think it happens because the database you are connecting is a MASTER instance.

Answer (score 2):

Try socat (http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/)

You can create a local file socket and connect it through a proxy (HTTP or SOCKS4/4A).
Something like:

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/mysql-proxy-socket,fork \ 
  SOCKS4:socks.example.com:mysql.example.com:3308
```

or

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/mysql-proxy-socket,fork \
  PROXY:squid.example.com:mysql.example.com:3308,proxyport=8888,proxyauth=user:pass
```

Comment: nice workaround, but tomorrow I will forget about this cause it's not standard, you know. Workbench should fix that bug instead.

Answer (score -2):

Just connect using Standard TCP/IP over SSH option in connection method.
then provide SSH username/password then mysql user/password and you are done!!

when proxy
create a tunnel in putty from SSH details and then connect in workbench using standard tcp/ip method

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaUE6.png)

@deepcell check screenshot of tunnel. this is how you have to create port 13306 and use like localhost:13306 to connect

Comment: It does not work that way. Mysql Workbench seems to use the IP address of VPN or Proxy instead of the IP address from the input field "SSH Hostname". It's a bug in workbench. Your answer solve nothing. Sorry.